# JMS Serializer unable to return a response

Tags: angularjs, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I recently included JMS Serializer bundle to handle and convert arrays into JSON

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function searchcarAction(Request $request) 
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   // $car = array();
    //$cars = $em->getRepository('VehicleBundle:Car')->findAll();
   // foreach ($cars as $cart) {
       // $car[] = array('id'=>$cart->getId(),'name' => $cart->getName());
   // }

    $cars = array('name' => 'john','middlename'=> 'gon');

    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');

    $jsonGroup= $serializer->serialize($cars,'json');

    return $jsonGroup;
}
public function carAction()
{
    return $this->render('VehicleBundle:Car:car_search.html.twig');
}
```

car.yml

```
search_car:
   path: /car-search
   defaults: { _controller: "VehicleBundle:Car:searchcar" }

car_action:
  path: /search
  defaults: { _controller: "VehicleBundle:Car:car" }
```

The JMS Serialiser is registeres in AppKernel.php

This  will return 500 error

> The controller must return a response ({"name":"john","middlename":"gon"} given).

```
  if (null === $response) {
     $msg .=' Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your   controller?';
  }
   throw new \LogicException($msg);
  }
  }
  return $this->filterResponse($response, $request, $type);
```

Whats wrong with my controller?

template

car_search.html.twig

```
 {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

 {% block body %}

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
 Search your Groups Here: <input type="text" ng-model="searchMe.name"/>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="exactMatch"/>Exact Match<br/>
 <div class="[ form-group ]">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="click" name="fancy-checkbox-default" id="fancy-checkbox-default" autocomplete="off" />
    <div class="[ btn-group ]">
        <label for="fancy-checkbox-default" class="[ btn btn-default ]">
            <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
            <span> </span>
        </label>
        <label for="fancy-checkbox-default" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
            Hide 
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<table id="table" class="table" ng-hide="click">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:searchMe:exactMatch | limitTo: 2">
            <td>//x.name//</td> 
            <td>//x.model//</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
</div>  
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {#{ parent() }#}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
        });

        app.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
            //$http.get("http://localhost:8093/voters/voters_angular")
            $http.get("{{ path('search_car') }}")
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.names= JSON.parse(response);
            });
        }]);
        //console.log(names);
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Is JMS serializer not working here?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string instead of Response object from your controller.

Instead of:

```
return $jsonGroup;
```

You should return response, like so for example:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($jsonGroup, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
```

Comment: I forgot to include my templates with Angular Js.I updated my question

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with error you're getting

Comment: Yes I understand,with your answer provided, the controller successfully display json.Any idea how to use it in Angular template provided?I think JMS not working in my bundle, It worked in my previous symfony 2.7 projects and the code in the controller as well as the routing exactly the same.I am usingSymfony  2.8 version this time

Comment: That was not part of the question and you shouldn't request more unrelated questions after original one has been answered. Make a new one.